# insert into looping based on select quantity

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

Based on a set data like this:

```
table_elements

element         quantity     description
00000001    2            element1   
00000002    3            element2
00000003    2            element3
```

How can you insert on another table as much records as it has quantity? 
If for example, it has a quantity of 2 it should create 2 new records with a new number and just adding it's quantity to the description.

Should end up something like this:

```
new_elements

element         description
00000004        element1 2
00000005        element1 3
00000006        element2 2  
00000007        element2 3
00000008        element2 4
...
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

[edit for clarification]

[Edit]

In your example should end up with something like this: (Let's suposse I want them to start in '2')

```
element     description     Number
20000001    element1    1
20000002    element1    2
20000003    element2    1
20000004    element2    2
20000005    element2    3
20000006    element3    1
20000007    element3    2
20000008    element4    1
20000009    element4    2
20000010    element4    3
```

In the table new_elements, 'element' doesn't really relate to the element on table_elements. that is already on the description. The numbering will be independent.

Comment: What's the maximum value that `quantity` could have?

Comment: could be variable, from 2 to whatever value. thanks

Comment: how is the value of `element` created ?

Comment: So 100,000 could be a legitimate value? What about 10,000,000?

Comment: @Squirrel the new element is created as last one +1 on that table.

Comment: @Larnu no, not that high. The highest one at the moment on the database is 800. But usually it is from 2 to 10.

Comment: what is the data type for `element` ?

Comment: it's nvarchar(8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with a Tally Table. I had built this with the assumption of no upper limit (well, there is one, 1M rows), which is appears isn't the case, but never mind. You can lower the number of rows in the Tally easily enough:

```
--Create initial sample data
CREATE TABLE dbo.Elements (element char(8),
                           quantity int,
                           [description] varchar(20));

INSERT INTO dbo.Elements (element,
                          quantity,
                          [description])
VALUES('00000001',2,'element1'),
      ('00000002',3,'element2'),
      ('00000003',2,'element3'),
      ('00000004',101246,'element4');
GO
--Create new table
CREATE TABLE dbo.NewElements (element char(8),
                              [description] varchar(20),
                              Number int);

GO
--Build a Tally table
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(Quantity) FROM dbo.Elements)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4, N N5, N N6) --1,000,000 rows
--Insert rows into new table
INSERT INTO dbo.NewElements (element,
                             description,
                             Number)
SELECT E.element,
       E.description,
       T.I
FROM dbo.Elements E
     JOIN Tally T ON E.quantity >= T.I;
GO

--Check they are all there
SELECT *
FROM dbo.NewElements
ORDER BY element,
         Number;
GO
--Clean up
DROP TABLE dbo.Elements;
DROP TABLE dbo.NewElements;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0551df42b7860c577dcc4fcad1ec26f5)